# How to use security review module

Tags: security

I have installed the [security review](http://drupal.org/project/security_review) module and enabled it but where to see the security flaws? There is not next page that I am being redirected to, tried google but not much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF it is Drupal 7

Navigate to Administer >> Reports >> Security Review to run the checklist.

Answer (score 1):

The project comes with a [README.txt file](http://drupalcode.org/project/security_review.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt) that is full of good advice. Most modules come with those, actually. I definitely suggest reading them.

> -- USAGE --
>
> Navigate to Administer >> Reports >> Security Review to run the checklist.
>
> If a check is enabled it will be run. You can enable or skip a check on this
>   page only after it has been run. Clicking on the 'Help' link beside each check
>   will provide details on why the check exists and what was found on the last run.

The same menu is used for both the Drupal 6, and Drupal 7 versions of the module.